# Exception in flatmap function when deploying to cluster

Tags: java, apache-flink, ignite

I have a flink-ignite application. I receive messages from kafka and process the mesages and then cache to ignite. when i run program in ide(intellij) and stand-alone jar there is no problem but when i deploy to cluster i got this exception (I have created the table earlier in the code.). Thanks in advance.
Note that connection variables are static in my main class.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at altosis.flinkcompute.compute.Main$2.flatMap(Main.java:95)
        at altosis.flinkcompute.compute.Main$2.flatMap(Main.java:85)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:50)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
        ... 22 more
```

````
            StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            environment.getConfig();
            environment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
            environment.setParallelism(1);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            props.setProperty("group.id","event-group");

            FlinkKafkaConsumer<EventSalesQuantity> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<EventSalesQuantity>("EventTopic",new EventSerializationSchema(),props);
            DataStream<EventSalesQuantity> eventDataStream = environment.addSource(consumer);

            KeyedStream<EventSalesQuantity, String> keyedEventStream = eventDataStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                    new AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarksImpl()
            ).
                    keyBy(new KeySelector<EventSalesQuantity, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String getKey(EventSalesQuantity eventSalesQuantity) throws Exception {
                            return  eventSalesQuantity.getDealer();
                        }
                    });

            DataStream<Tuple2<EventSalesQuantity,Integer>> eventSinkStream = keyedEventStream.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.DAYS),Time.hours(21))).aggregate(new AggregateImpl());
            ignite = Ignition.start();
            ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800");
            igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg);

            System.out.println(">>> Thin client put-get example started.");
            igniteClient.query(
                    new SqlFieldsQuery(String.format(
                            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Eventcache (eventtime VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, bayi VARCHAR, sales INT ) WITH \"VALUE_TYPE=%s\"",
                            EventSalesQuantity.class.getName()
                    )).setSchema("PUBLIC")
            ).getAll();

            eventSinkStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<Tuple2<EventSalesQuantity, Integer>>("localhost:9092","SinkEventTopic",new EventSinkSerializationSchema()));
            Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/");
            eventSinkStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<EventSalesQuantity, Integer>, Object>() {
                @Override
                public void flatMap(Tuple2<EventSalesQuantity, Integer> eventSalesQuantityIntegerTuple2, Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {
                    Ignsql= conn.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO Eventcache (eventtime, bayi, sales) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

                    Ignsql.setString(1, eventSalesQuantityIntegerTuple2.f0.getTransactionDate());
                    Ignsql.setString(2, eventSalesQuantityIntegerTuple2.f0.getDealer());
                    Ignsql.setInt(3, eventSalesQuantityIntegerTuple2.f1);
                    Ignsql.execute();
                    Ignsql.close();
                }
            });

           // eventSinkStream.print();
            environment.execute();```
````

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what the values of all the variables/fields/etc. are at line 95?

Comment: @user2478398 yes i have tried. There is no problem with fields. Also i can see the data on table when run program in  ide.

Comment: That doesn't prove anything.  When you run using a debugger it is likely to mask concurrency bugs ... like pugs caused by inadequate synchronization.  Unfortunately, the code snippets you provided are not sufficient for a proper diagnosis.

Comment: @StephenC i have edited my code sir. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you say "Note that connection variables are static in my main class", you're talking about `Ignsql`. If so, then your code won't work because that variable isn't available to your map function, which is serialized and distributed by the JobManager before the workflow actually starts running.

You should create a RichFlatMapFunction class, and in the `open()` method you set up the connection variable(s) that you need, and then close them in the `close()` method. If you have configuration parameters required to set up the connection variable, you'd pass those into the RichFlatMapFunction's constructor and save them in (non-transient) variables, and then use them in the `open()` method.